# Appending input from csv file to a dictionary including duplicate values for a unique key

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

First, I want to say that I am new to programming. That said, using Python 2.76, I'm trying to take a text file, read it in with csv, and then create a dictionary with a key equal to the first column in the file. Here is an example of the type of file I want to use (sorry for the bad formatting, there are three columns, each with a given value of either visitid, date, or time):

> visitid    cdate   ctime
>
> OMHioJh8XEeq7152       6/15/2007   06:00
>
> OMHioJh8XEeq7152   6/14/2007   07:10
>
> OMHioJh8XEeq7152   6/11/2007   14:21
>
> t2v0TjgroLTI6118   4/28/2006   14:18
>
> t2v0TjgroLTI6118   5/1/2006    04:00

Specifically, given this kind of list, I want to make a key in the dictionary equal to the value of the first column, and for the value have the remaining columns as a list.  Finally, I want to append the value with another list if there are duplicates of the value in column 1 to form a list of lists, so to speak.  This is what I have so far, after doing some research on here and elsewhere:

```
def test_results(filename):
import csv
with open(filename,"rU") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
    result = {}
    for row in reader:
        key = row[0]
        if key in result:
            result[row[0]].append(row[1])
        else:
            result[row[0]] = key
        result[key]=row[1:]
    print result
```

This works, but it does not append the values to make a list of lists, and only adds to the dictionary the last row for any unique visitID.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an error about str objects having no append method?

Comment: I did have an error like that at first, but after I changed a few things, for whatever reason it does not give me that error anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

def test_results(filename):
    with open(filename, "rU") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
        result = defaultdict(list)
        # Skip header row
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            result[row[0]].append(row[1:])
```

`defaultdict(list)` will assume an empty list if the key is not present in the dictionary. Given the input provide in the question, `result` will contain:

```
{'OMHioJh8XEeq7152': [['6/15/2007', '06:00'],
                      ['6/14/2007', '07:10'],
                      ['6/11/2007', '14:21']],
 't2v0TjgroLTI6118': [['4/28/2006', '14:18'], 
                      ['5/1/2006', '04:00']]}
```

---

If you want a more flexible format, you should convert your date and time strings into a [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object using [`dateutil.parser.parse`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from dateutil import parser


def test_results(filename):
    with open(filename, "rU") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
        result = defaultdict(list)
        # Skip header line
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            result[row[0]].append(parser.parse(' '.join(row[1:])))
```

Which yields:

```
{'OMHioJh8XEeq7152': [datetime.datetime(2007, 6, 15, 6, 0),
                      datetime.datetime(2007, 6, 14, 7, 10),
                      datetime.datetime(2007, 6, 11, 14, 21)],
 't2v0TjgroLTI6118': [datetime.datetime(2006, 4, 28, 14, 18),
                      datetime.datetime(2006, 5, 1, 4, 0)]}
```

Comment: I really like your solution, but when I use it on the file I am working with it gives me the dictionary of lists which I want but it does so many times (ie: 10+ duplicate dictionaries containing the same thing). Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: Sure.  I'm new to stackoverflow though--where is the option to upload a file?

Comment: I fixed it!  The problem was that the "print result" line was in the for loop, causing it to be duplicated.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No problem, nice to be able to help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
    if key in result:
        result[row[0]].append(row[1:])
    else:
        result[row[0]] = key
        result[key] = [row[1:]]
```

Comment: That is very close, I think--it gives me the full length of the first row, but only gives me the date of the other rows.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: ah! I fixed it.  2nd line above should be .append(row[1:]) with a colon.  Please accept as the answer if it works!

Comment: You can drop `result[row[0]] = key`, it doesn't make any sense. Since `key = row[0]`, you are really saying `result[key] = key`